# Deleting "child" records on delete (reverse foreign key constraint?)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

To illustrate my problem, I have 3 tables.

`Table A` **AND** `Table B` both individually have FK `C_ID` that reference `Table C`'s PK.

I want `Table C`'s rows to be deleted if their related rows in `Table A` or `Table B` is deleted.

**FK constraints seem to only work one way. How do I deal with this?**

*To clarify, A and B has a 1:1 relationship with C. To be more precise it's a (A,B)parent-child(C) relationship where the child's existence depends on the parent's.*

Comment: Sometimes logic is best done in the application code.

Comment: @RickJames Yea, that's what I did in the end. Tagged it to the delete event of my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a delete trigger to remove the records from table C when a delete occurs on table a or b.

There is a question from SO where the answer gives you a nice example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818191/mysql-trigger-delete-from-table-after-delete

But to give you the rough idea from that answer:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_c_delete AFTER DELETE on table_a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM table_c
    WHERE table_c.parent_id = old.id;
END
```

Comment: For those coming here using MySQL and thinking about implementing a trigger now, keep in mind that in MySQL triggers don't fire on cascaded actions: stackoverflow.com/a/6095593/1813669